# Why my hex inverter chips (all three of them) are not producing a HIGH output with low input?

Tags: led, current-limiting

I wont say I am great at reading datasheets, but I noticed that for 74LS06 chip, Ioh is 0.25 mA and Iol is 40mA. Does that mean it can light-up an LED when its output is low but not when its output is HIGH (a forward biased LED of course)?

If yes, does it mean that all those chips whose Ioh or Iol is lesser than required to light-up an LED can't glow the LEDs even when it is forward biased? Please help. It means a lot.

Also, I have tested with multimeter, the output voltage of three 74LS06 chips with low input is 0.04v.

Comment: You'll get some light out of a LED at 0.25mA, but basically you're right.That's why traditionally, LEDs were driven with active low outputs, resistor and LED to 5V. As to why ... in those days you could make great NPN transistors. PNP,not so much. (This applies to all TTL, but Trevor's right, 7406 is open collector where the pull-up transistor is omitted completely)

Comment: Ioh of open collector = 0 and only possible with Pullup R where 0.25mA  = 5V/20k

Comment: @BrianDrummond Thanks. I am so glad I asked this question as all the explanations here helped me a lot. @ Tony I am looking at your diagrams below in the answer. I shall revert soon

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you look at the data sheet for the [74LS06](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74ls06.pdf), you will see the following.

[image]

Note it says the outputs are open-collector. That means it can sink current but can not source it. (Well it can actually source a little current as leakage or more if you pull the output below the bottom rail.)

Looking at the internals confirms this.

[image]

If you compare that to a push-pull output like the [74xx04](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74ls04.pdf)..

[image]

You can see that the output has two transistors. The bottom one is similar to the output of the open collector device and is turned on when the output is low and pulls the output down, sinking current. The top transistor is turned on when the output is high, it sources current and pushes the output high. Hence the name push-pull output.

On an open-collector device, with no pull-up on the outputs, you will not be able to measure much voltage on the outputs when the outputs are high.

You can use the open-collector device to pull current down from Vcc through an LED if you so desire, but do not exceed the maximum output low sink current.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCHBRY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As [Gee Bee](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/356372/139766) mentioned, you can also do it, without the inversion, by shunting out the LED, as shown below. However, this method wastes power since current will always be flowing through the resistor. It actually uses more power with the LED off than when it is on. So I do not recommend this method.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpDLPj.png)</sup>

Do not try the shunt method with a push-pull invertor though.

Comment: I literally had no idea what open-collector meant. All I thought earlier was that it can work both sides by just making sure that the LED is forward biased. Now I understand that an open-collector cannot source a current but only collect it. And as @TonyM mentioned above, I should be using HC chips which are capable of sourcing current also. I still have a question. What does it mean that the output is HIGH if it cannot be of use to light-up any LEDs? I mean, does that simply refer to the output voltage is HIGH but the current output (Ioh) wont be sufficient?

Comment: If the OC output is "low" it connects the output to the GND, hence it can sink current. When it is "high", it is not connected to anywhere, hence no current will flow.

Comment: @TravelServe normally Open collector devices rely on some form of pull-up on the line they are controlling. Be that just a resistor or an LED in your case. As such HIGH in this case more means  NOT Low. Using this device to drive your LEDs is fine though, as long as the resistor and LED goes up to Vcc. That is, use the invertor as a bottom side switch.

Comment: @GeeBee Now I get it. So, in short, the answer to my question in description "If yes, does it mean that all those chips whose Ioh or Iol is lesser than required to light-up an LED can't glow the LEDs even when it is forward biased? Please help. It means a lot." is a yes right? I am g lad you guys rescued me out of this.

Comment: @Trevor_G Yes, that 'NOT low' helps alot. So, even if it is HIGH doesn't gaurantee that it will light-up the LED unless it is capable of sourcing enough current to it.

Comment: @TravelServe yes you would need a push-pull output to drive a LED directly in the high state. See my edits for open collector driving suggestions.

Comment: @Trevor_G Yes, I am looking at the shunt diagrams you have provided. I hope I get this concept of push and pull resistors today itself.

Comment: @TravelServe I expanded the answer a bit to show a comparison with a push-pull device.

Comment: Thank @Trevor_G. Your diagrams are really helpful since I like the white-box explanationa nd you have shown the internal of the inverter chip. So, the GND end of the bottom transistor is sinking (collecting the current) while the upper one sources the current. So unless I use a pull-up resistor to sink the current finally into the output, I wont be able to measure the precise voltage due to the push-pull scenario inside. Right?

Comment: @TravelServe right. You need a pull-up if you want to check the voltage.

Answer (score 3):

You've picked a part with an open-collector outputs. The IOH output-when-high current is more of a leakage current when the output is disabled. The output high current is normally provided by external circuitry i.e. a pull-up resistor.

Modernise your choice of logic family a little and look at a 74HCT04. That can source or sink 4 mA which is fine for a low-current LED.

Or make an active-low driver and make the most of the high sink current capability of your 74LS04 or 74LS06. Connect your LED-and-resistor across your supply rail and the gate's output.

Comment: Thanks for such a good insight towards HC chips compared to TTL chips Tony. It will help me when sourcing chips next time.

Comment: @TravelServe, you're welcome and please read up on logic families on Wikipedia etc. You'll see that plain 74, 74LS, 74HC, 74HCT, 74F, 74LVC and all the rest are all types of TTL logic chips. So it's not TTL vs HC :-)

Comment: Oh. My bad, I am learning :). I will surely look into the internals of HC vs LS which makes the former capable of sourcing current additionally. I want to follow you guys' profiles but cannot see any option.

Answer (score 2):

@TonyM is right. But, iff for some reason you are stuck to using this part with OC output, you can connect a resistor (e.g. 470 ohm) between 5V and the output, and the LED between the output and GND.

When the output is "unconnected" (aka high), the LED can lit. When the output is low, it will short the LED and the led is off. (Note that during this "off" mode a small current flows trough the resistor, which must be less than 40mA to keep within the safe Iol range.)

Comment: I will need to draw what you suggested and understand what is happening. I will revert when I am able to grasp on this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Note that this arrangement will consume more current when the LED is off than when it's on! The voltage across the resistor will be higher because the full 5V is across it instead of 5V less the LED forward voltage.

Comment: I just need one last clarification. As @ Trevor & @ Geebee mentioned the use of pull-up resistor in series and shunt, can you please tell me when will the LED glow and when not, in each case (i.e. for output HIGH and output LOW for series and shunt)?

Comment: In the suggested arrangement, resistor is always a pullup, i.e. it is connecting the output to 5V, "pulls" it towards 5V when possible. If you put the LED between output and GND, it is OFF when the output is LOW. 

However, you can pick a different arrangement: 5V - series resistor - LED - output. In this case, the LED is ON when the output is LOW.

Answer (score 2):

Ioh of open collector = 0 and only possible with Pullup R where 0.25mA is wrong

read again.  It is Vol =0.25V typ  @Iol=16mA

which implies low side switch with Rce=0.25V/16mA= 16 Ohms

and high side is 0mA unless pullup R.

So using Common ANode CA 7-seg.  current is If=(Vcc-Vf_led)/Rs

e.g. lets say Vf=2.2V @ 10mA  and Vcc=4.75V then Rs=(Vcc-Vf)/If= (4.75-2.2)/10mA= 255 Ohms   ( choose closest for 5V)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6jdMv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks @Tony, this further calrifies my understanding and calculating the pull-up resistor values. However, I am not sure about 0.25v value for Vol since in the datasheet, Vol is 0.4v when Iol sinked is 16mA.

Comment: Se e how I calculated Rce.. this varies in batches so 0.25 is typical giving 16 ohms and 0.4V is max yielding 25 Ohms.  This 25 Ohms  similar to RdsOn in 3.3V type CMOS logic in ARM.  generally RdsOn  is 50% same as Rce, but they dont tell you.. just typ and max Vol@Iol. Even experts inthe forum dont know this. Now you do.

Comment: Oh yes! It is the maximum voltage, and 0.25v is the typical one. Indeed, this is an interesting practical use of knowing the range of resistance to be used. I generally use 220 Ohm resistors, which is fine as noted in your calculations.

I just noticed that you have linked to some useful books. Do you have a recommendation to further study and build concepts on these lines (aka open-collector, TTL, LS and HC, limitations of Multimeter while measuring OC outputs, say HIGH output etc?

Comment: No. Why don't you research my answers on this subject or Rce and RdsOn and ESR?